# Operation with graphs

Tags: graph-theory, algebraic-topology

I´m trying to apply the Euler theorem (V+F=E+2 on plane graphs) for a concrete graph (the following one).

Thing is that I can use to operations:
1) Delete a node of grade 2 (that is, 2 edges on it)
2) Delete a edge

The idea is obtain a graph with 3 nodes (and grade of all them will be 2), so then apply a Lemma that asserts: V + F = E + 2.

Here are my steps:

[image]

Please, help me. Maybe I´m wrong, but I think that this is the idea.

Thanks!

Comment: In 4, you still need the vertex in the middle of the "cross." Then the are a few more steps after that before you obtain the triangle.

Comment: After 4, assuming it's still meant to have a node in the middle, delete one of the corner  ones and put up with getting a double edge. I don't think that's avoidable (but I might be wrong). Then delete the corner node with the double edge.

Comment: Well, I forget to put the node in the middle, sorry. Don´t forget that only you can remove node of grade 2 (exact 2).

Comment: With a double edge, that would be satisfied.

Comment: My thought of splitting it in two then dismantling one piece doesn't work since the last node can't be deleted.

Answer (score 1):

Finally I get it.

Thing is that for apply the Lemma its enough to obtain 3 nodes with any of grade at least 1. So this a (probably) solution:

[image]

Thanks for the support!  :)